# Firebase Functions check if the user id in the database is the current user id

Tags: node.js, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im working on sending notifications between android devices using Firebase functions. When A-Device sends a message to B-Device, the message will be stored in the firebasedatabase under A-Device Id und B-Device Id like this [image] the problem is the function which i wrote checks always A-Device id therefore it sends the notification always to A-Device. it means when A-Device sends to B-Device the notification will be sent to A-Device
this is my Node.js code. please help me ;(

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
//const mId = firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken();
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Messages/{mId}/{uId}/{messageId}').onWrite(event =>{
const mId = event.params.mId; //getting mId
const uId = event.params.uId; //getting uId
  const val = event.data.val(); //getting the values from event
  const from = val.from; //from value
  const type = val.type; //type value
  const message = val.message;





  console.log("user_name ",user_name);
  console.log("user_email ",user_email);


  const getDeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${uId}/`).once('value');//getting device token function

  return getDeviceToken.then(snapshot =>{ //executing the function
  const DeviceToken = snapshot.val().DeviceToken;
  console.log ("Device Token is ",DeviceToken);
  if (from == mId) {
  delete  DeviceToken;
} 
  const getName = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${from}/`).once('value');//getting device token function

  return getName.then(snapshot =>{ //executing the function
    const Name = snapshot.val().Name;
    console.log ("Sender is ",Name);

  const payload = {
    data: {
      title: `${Name} sent you a message.`,
      body: `${message}`
    }
  };
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(DeviceToken,payload).then(response => {
    console.log (`Notification has been sent to  ${Name}`);
  });});
  });
});
```

Comment: Am i right that "my id" = A-device and "user id" = B-device? Since the message is indeed from B-device, you should send it to A-device, right?

     getDeviceToken should use mId (A-device) if Im not mistaken

Comment: I need to tell the Firebase Functions, that only mId should be checked but I dont know how to get my Id in this case